# Localhost: Image from origin 'null' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm opening the page on two computers, both ip and localhost tried:

Strangely, for one computer, the `http://192.168.1.100/dev` didn't work and `http://localhost/dev` did. For the other, neither worked. It says,

> Image from origin 'null' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin `'http://localhost'` is therefore not allowed access.

None of the answers I found seem to work. And I don't understand why it only worked on `localhost` on one computer. Any suggestions?

Edit:

1. Browser: Chrome Version 34.0.1847.11 beta
2. `http://127.0.0.1/dev` didn't work either
3. The uploaded version on server didn't work either

Comment: Can you pls share which browser you are using. Also please try the url `http://127.0.0.1/dev` and share the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, it was the `AdBlock` plugin that blocked the file.

The name of the directory containing the blocked file was `AD16`. Somehow the other `AD01`, `AD09`, `AD22`, `AD27` worked fine, but not `AD16`.

Disabling `AdBlock` and everything works fine.

The same problem would have occurred on any chrome with the plugin on, so we changed the name of the directory to `AD_16`.