# Domain has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-config

I have made a `codeigniter` application. I uploaded it to `http://www.domain.com`.

But `Chrome` continuously give the message...

`Font from origin http://www.domain.com has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy. Origin 'http://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access`.

I set my `base_url` in `config.php` as `http://www.domain.com` but the error still persists.

When I changed the `base_url` as `http://domain.com`, it gives error as...

`Font from origin http://domain.com has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access`.

I've written the below code in my `web.config`, but no result.

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 IST" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
</staticContent>
```

I have seen [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213207/localhost-image-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origi), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768518/image-from-origin-file-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resour), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998629/cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy-blocking-glyphicons-from-bootstrap-in-codei) these links, but unable to resolve.

What should I do ?

**UPDATE**

Actually the error comes from the domain name. If I write `www.domain.com` while my `config.php` `base_url()` is `http://domain.com`, it gives the error. On the other hand, if my If I write `domain.com` while my `config.php` `base_url()` is `http://www.domain.com`, it also gives the error.

Comment: download the font folder and add it in your file structure will solve this problem

Comment: @Spartan thanks for the answer, but for your information, font folder is inside the file structure. Please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

The issue resolved.
(I don't know whether it gives another error in future)

**Solution #1**
(Probably the best solution):

For IIS 7 : (Source: [Enable Cross-Origin Resource](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html))

Add the below code in your `web.config` file...

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

For IIS 6: [CORS on IIS6](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html)

For Apache : [CORS on Apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

For other platform: [CORS support to server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

---

**Solution #2**
(I don't know whether it works in all servers, but for me it worked well.)

Source: [Codeigniter base url issue with www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553513/codeigniter-base-url-issue-with-www)

Configure your `base_url` in `codeigniter` `config/config.php` file

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```